# How do I get radarr.service to start automatically?

Tags: systemd, services, vim, mono

I have installed radarr successfully, but it will only run if I use terminal and type:

```
mono ~/Radarr/Radarr.exe
```

When I close terminal, radarr will stop working so I followed the instructions on wiki github and varhowto to create auto-start using `systemd` with this command.

```
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/radarr.service
```

I have tried this using `vim` an `nano` as well.  Here is the text I used changing vh to "david"

```
[Unit]
Description=Radarr Daemon
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
# Change and/or create the required user and group.
User=david
Group=david

Type=simple

# Change the path to Radarr or mono here if it is in a different location for you.
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mono --debug /home/david/Radarr/Radarr.exe -nobrowser
TimeoutStopSec=20
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure

# These lines optionally isolate (sandbox) Radarr from the rest of the system.
# Make sure to add any paths it might use to the list below (space-separated).
#ReadWritePaths=/opt/Radarr /path/to/movies/folder
#ProtectSystem=strict
#PrivateDevices=true
#ProtectHome=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After I save and exit, I run the following:

```
sudo systemctl enable --now radarr.service
```

... but I get the following error and font know what to correct now:

```
david@david-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo systemctl enable --now radarr.service
Failed to start radarr.service: Unit radarr.service has a bad unit file setting.
See system logs and 'systemctl status radarr.service' for details.
david@david-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo systemctl status radarr.service
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of radarr.service ch>
● radarr.service - Radarr Daemon
     Loaded: bad-setting (Reason: Unit radarr.service has a bad unit file setting.)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/radarr.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: inactive (dead)

Oct 13 12:13:05 david-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: radarr.service: Service has >
Oct 13 12:16:47 david-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: radarr.service: Service has >
```

I swear this was working before I added a 1TB HDD and zeroed it for use with linux.  I did have a GRUB screen come up so used the tool in linux via USB boot and fixed the GRUB issue. Everything is working except radarr will not stay running. As I mentioned and it will not auto-start.  I'm not sure what the system logs are that it says to look at.

Answer (score 1):

The ExecStart= path was incorrect. I figured out what to change for the path and it’s working now.